# How to use combination of annotate and aggregate sum in Django ORM

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

from the below table I need the output has,

> [(Apple,21.0), (Orange,12.0) ,(Grapes,15.0) ]

basically fruits grouped with the sum of their cost

date in (dd/mm//yyyy)

```
Fruits Table
date        item    price
01/01/2021  Apple   5.0
01/01/2021  Orange  2.0
01/01/2021  Grapes  3.0
01/02/2021  Apple   7.0
01/02/2021  Orange  4.0
01/02/2021  Grapes  5.0
01/03/2021  Apple   9.0
01/03/2021  Orange  6.0
01/03/2021  Grapes  7.0
...........
....
```

models.py

```
 class Fruits(models.Model):
        item = models.CharField(max_length=32)
        date = models.DateField()
        price = models.FloatField()
```

I tried the below code its not working as expected

```
fruit_prices = Fruits.objects.filter(date__gte=quarter_start_date,date__lte=quarter_end_date)
               .aggregate(Sum('price')).annotate('item').values('item','price').distinct()
```

Comment: Can you share the model?

Comment: The filtering also looks odd: `quarter_start_date` is used twice?

Comment: Sorry its date__lte=quarter_end_date

Comment: can you share (relevant parts) of your model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem   added model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a GROUP BY with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Fruits.objects.filter(
    date__range=(quarter_start_date, quarter_end_date)
).values('item').annotate(
    total=Sum('price')
).order_by('item')
```

This will generate a queryset that looks like:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'item': 'Apple', 'total': 21.0},
    {'item': 'Grapes', 'total': 15.0},
    {'item': 'Orange', 'total': 12.0}
]>
```

a collection of dictionaries where the keys `'item'` and `total` map to the item and the sum of all the `price`s for that `item` that satisfy the given datetime range.

I would however advise to make a `FruitItem` model and work with a `ForeignKey`, to convert your database modeling to the [*Third Normal Form* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

Comment: instead of order_by('item') it shouldn't be annotate  ??

Comment: @SivaPerumal: yes. The `total` should be in the `.annotate(..)` clause. Forgot that `.values(..)` does not work with aggregates. Updated.